# Why do we need sub-gradient methods for non-differentiable functions?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, gradient-descent, subgradient

Why do we need sub-gradient methods for non-differentiable functions?

Consider optimizing $f(x) = max_{i}   (a_{i}^Tx+b_{i})$. Clearly this is non-differentiable at multiple points, and the conventional way is to solve this using sub-gradient descent.

We know that this function however, is differentiable almost everywhere. Can't we use normal gradient descent, and if we end up at a non-differentiable point, simple perturb the value of x by $\epsilon$ and compute the gradient?

Comment: Are you familiar with the "zigzagging" problem of gradient descent on poorly scaled problems? At the location of nondifferentiability, the function has infinitely poor scaling.

Comment: Slide 5 in lecture 1 ("gradient methods") of Vandenberghe's [UCLA 236c notes](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/ee236c.html) gives an example of a convex, nondifferentiable problem where gradient descent fails to converge to a global minimizer, despite never encountering a point where the objective function is nondifferentiable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Non-differentiability of $f(x)$ can cause problems even in situations where a gradient descent method never encounters a point where the gradient isn't defined.  For example, try gradient descent on $f(x)=|x|$ using any fixed step size.  For most starting points, the method will not converge even though it never hits the single bad point $x=0$ where $f'(x)$ isn't defined.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this is so?

Comment: Pick a fixed step size $\alpha$.  Start at any $x^{(0})$ that is not a multiple of $\alpha$.  Run the algorithm.  Because the gradient of $f$ is always $\pm 1$, the iteration will end oscillating between two points on either side of $0$.

Comment: how does subgradient method solve this problem? Even in that, the subgradient will always be +1 or -1, unless we evaluate it at the minimum.

Comment: Subgradient methods have to use more sophisticated step length selection rules.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of methods for optimizing a function that is not differentiable at some points.  Sub-gradient methods (e.g., sub-gradient projection) have been tailored for efficient implementation and have been shown to work on a wide variety of optimization problems.  Yes, you can try to graft an ad-hoc "random perturbation" method onto a traditional gradient-descent algorithm, but there are perils in making the "wrong" perturbation (viz., wrong dimension), particularly in high dimensional search spaces.

Why not simply use one of the well-tested methods based on sub-gradients?

Answer (score 1):

If you study the convergence proof of GD you will notice that differentiability is usually not the only requirement but also Lipschitz continuity of the gradient. The Lipschitz constant is very important when choosing a **fixed** stepsize.

Comment: how is this connected to non-differentiability, and the perturbration thing i was talking about?

Comment: if you understand the importance of the stepsize you'll understand. the crucial difference between GD, subgradient method and the pertubation method you propose is not the differentiability (although it seems this way) but the stepsizes you have to choose in order to guarantee convergence.

Comment: I understand subgradient methods only converge with square summable step sizes. So what you are trying to say is that the differentiability is not the problem, but the lipschitz number? I am not too clear on this. Can you take the example of $|x|=1$

Comment: ok, take the example of $\min |x|$ and any positive stepsize let's call it $\lambda$. if you start from any point other than $\pm \lambda$ GD descent (with constant stepsize) will not converge although you never hit a point of nondifferentiability..

Comment: what i meant to say earlier was: also in GD you cannot take any stepsize and expect convergence! usually you have an upper bound like $\frac1L$ where $L$ is the Lipschitz constant of the gradient! so the point is even if you never hit a point of nondifferentiability the is no Lipschitzconstant in the nondifferentiable case

Comment: So the general problem with non-differentiable functions is there never exists lipschitz constants? In that case, we can expect similar problems with differentiable functions without lipschitz constants?

Comment: yes, same problem

Answer (score 1):

Constant step-size can only be used when the function has $L-$Lipschitz gradient (step-size can be chosen as 1/L). However, if gradient of the function is not Lipschitz but only continuous, we can use backtracking line-search. Proposition 1.2.1 in the book Nonlinear Programming of Dimitri Bertsekas already mentioned the convergence for gradient methods using this step-size together with a broad class of approximate directions (not need to be exact gradient).

For non-differentiable functions, when we use backtracking line-search, even if all the iterative points are differentiable, the algorithm can converge to a non-stationary point, see Figure 1 in this paper [https://sites.math.washington.edu/~burke/papers/reprints/96-gs_highlights.pdf](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Eburke/papers/reprints/96-gs_highlights.pdf)
with  Rosenbrock function.

However, for your question, I believe that the answer is yes, if we use diminishing step-size (or square summable but not summable one). You may try some numerical experiments for this. Sorry but I do not know any theoretical result in the official mathematics paper about it. But again, I believe that the answer is yes.